# How to set differnce color of divider and text on TextInputLayout when use setError()

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I want to use difference color between divider and error text when setError()[image]

Comment: `<item name="textColorError">@color/error</item>` add this to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
android:textColor="@color/lang_color"
android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat theme you can change it from your app theme just set below value. This will set error color to all TextInputLayout in your app.

```
<item name="textColorError">@color/error</item>
```

If you don't want it everywhere create a separate style for your TextInputLayout and add same line to it and set this style to your TextInputLayout.

Comment: Thanks  for reply, But I want difference color of divider and text error view, I try to use textColorError but it's make both of view are same color.

Answer (score 0):

With the version 1.2.0 of the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use the attributes:

- `app:boxStrokeErrorColor`: to define the underline color
- `app:errorTextColor`: to define the color used by the error message

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/secondaryColor"
        app:errorTextColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
        .../>
```

[image]